# Expected Downtime to update Amazon RDS to mysql 5.6

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-5.6

Recently I've got notification from Amazon saying

> **Updates available:** You have OS upgrades pending for 1 instance(s). To
>   opt in to these upgrades, select a DB instance, open the Instance
>   Actions menu, and click Upgrade Now, Upgrade at Next Window. If you do
>   nothing, optional upgrades will remain available and mandatory
>   upgrades will be applied to your instances at a later date specified
>   by AWS. You can review the type of the upgrade in the Maintenance
>   column. **Note: The instances will be taken offline during the OS
>   upgrade.**

I have Amazon RDS instance with configuration given below

- Class: db.m3.xlarge
- Engine: mysql 5.5.40
- Storage Type: Magnetic
- Multi-AZ: Yes
- Storage: 250 GB (55% used)

I need to know the expected downtime to update.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your downtime will be minimal because your instance is set up as Multi-AZ. In this configuration, the standby instance is upgraded first, then a failover to the standby instance occurs, then the first instance (now in standby) is upgraded. Your only downtime will be during the failover process, which is usually 1-2 minutes in duration.